# R: transposing replicates of different measurements stored in rows into single columns

Tags: r, dataframe

I am very sorry if the title is misleading, as I don't know how to explain this properly (not sure what the terminology would be).

I have some data that basically looks like this:

```
a<-c('AA01','AA02','AB01')
b<-c('AA','AA','AB')
c<-c('Y','N','N')
d<-c(1,2,3)
e<-c(4,5,6)
f<-c(7,8,9)
g<-c(11,22,33)
h<-c(44,55,66)
i<-c(77,88,99)
cols<-c("SampID","Characteristic1","Characteristic2","Mes1Rep1","Mes1Rep2","Mes1Rep3","Mes2Rep1","Mes2Rep2","Mes2Rep3")


df<-data.frame(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i)
colnames(df)<-cols
df

  SampID Characteristic1 Characteristic2 Mes1Rep1 Mes1Rep2 Mes1Rep3 Mes2Rep1 Mes2Rep2 Mes2Rep3
1   AA01              AA               Y        1        4        7       11       44       77
2   AA02              AA               N        2        5        8       22       55       88
3   AB01              AB               N        3        6        9       33       66       99
```

In this example, Mes1Rep1 refers to the first replicate of a type of measurement, Mes2Rep2 the second replicate of that measurement, and so on. I would like to arrange the replicates in columns instead. Something more like this:

```
  SampID Characteristic1 Characteristic2 Replicates Measurement1 Measurement2
1   AA01              AA               Y       Rep1            1           11
2   AA01              AA               Y       Rep2            4           44
3   AA01              AA               Y       Rep3            7           77
4   AA02              AA               N       Rep1            2           22
5   AA02              AA               N       Rep2            5           55
6   AA02              AA               N       Rep3            8           88
7   AB01              AB               N       Rep1            3           33
8   AB01              AB               N       Rep2            6           66
9   AB01              AB               N       Rep3            9           99
```

How would I go about doing this in R? I think I can just transpose the rows themselves, but is there some way to also copy the redundant values (such as "SampID" in this example) automatically?

Or is there no choice but to do this manually?

Thank you for taking the time to read this, and for offering your help and/or guidance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `melt` from `data.table` which can take multiple `measure` `patterns`

```
library(data.table)
melt(setDT(df), measure = patterns("Mes1", "Mes2"), 
   variable.name = "Replicates", 
    value.name = c("Measurement1", "Measurement2"))[
      order(SampID)][, Replicates := paste0("Rep", Replicates)][]
#   SampID Characteristic1 Characteristic2 Replicates Measurement1 Measurement2
#1:   AA01              AA               Y       Rep1            1           11
#2:   AA01              AA               Y       Rep2            4           44
#3:   AA01              AA               Y       Rep3            7           77
#4:   AA02              AA               N       Rep1            2           22
#5:   AA02              AA               N       Rep2            5           55
#6:   AA02              AA               N       Rep3            8           88
#7:   AB01              AB               N       Rep1            3           33
#8:   AB01              AB               N       Rep2            6           66
#9:   AB01              AB               N       Rep3            9           99
```

---

Or use `reshape` from `base R`

```
reshape(df, idvar = c("SampID", "Characteristic1", "Characteristic2"), 
       varying = list(4:6, 7:9), direction = "long")
```

Comment: Thank you so much @akrun, this works like a charm! If I may ask, is there any way to accomplish the same task without using `data.table`?

Comment: @Dunois  We can use `reshape` from `base R`

Comment: Nice! I guess I have some documentation to read to understand all of this better. Thank you once again, and I wish you a pleasant weekend ahead. :)

Comment: @Dunois  If you check the `?melt` or `?reshape` would get more info regarding the arguments along with example.  Have a great weekend to you as well.  Thanks